# Team Foundation Administrator member cant create/delete branches

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc, azure-devops-server-2020

I'm having pretty strange problem and ill try to explain as best as i can since English is not my native language.

As member of Team Foundation Administrator group ( and also added myself to Project administrators ) on Azure Devops Server 2020 - TFS repository ( on premise ) recently ( as of last week but, I'm not sure as of when, because last time i tried and managed to perform all tasks was 1 month ago before that ) I'm facing following problems:

- in project I can delete all files/folders except one ( getting TF14098 - User needs read permission , checked security everything is allow for my user )
- for that reason I can delete branch were folder is ( even if i convert branch to folder )
- cant create new branches from main branch ( getting TF14098 - User needs read permission )
- cant destroy branch/folder from developer command prompt
- i can create branch from dev.com.prompt but only if i dont use /checkin param. I can checkin that pending change from visual studio.

I tried putting other user in same group ( through administration console on server and in project admin groups through web ) and result is same he cant create/delete branches

Any hint what I can try to find cause?

Hope this all sounds meaningful.

Ill be glad to provide any additional info.

Event viewer on both server and locally dont capture anything.
Tried starting profiler on TFS database bit i can see anything meaningful.
My security team is telling me that they done see anything in logs or wherever they are looking.